# Display flight paths in google maps

Tags: google-maps

Hi I want to display flight paths in Google maps. I have the geo coordinates and want to create something like this on this image: http://main.makeuseoflimited.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/flightarrivals.png?54167

Has anyone a good example? Is this possible?

Thanks
Nik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about the API docs?

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html

You can add markers, lines, text etc.  All described in the API.

Example shamelessly grabbed from the docs on how to draw a polyline on a map:

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      myOptions);
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

There are lots more examples on the Google pages.

Comment: Hi, Looks good, but here is only one line with 4 pints. I need that the start point is one and to display all routes from this point to the others. Like the image, what I have linked.

Comment: Well - just lather, rinse, repeat. No one is going to post the exact code you need, so you will need to take the API and apply it to your specific problem.  If you get stuck during the implementation come back and post a specific problem and the friendly SO people will be more than happy to help.